# NLA Track changes when not editing

Tags: nla-editor

I have two NLA tracks in sequence.  The first has jogging motions with cycles modifiers.  There is also a Follow Path modifier that is animated to stop at a frame.  The second will have movements *after* the jogging sequence.

If I *Start Editing stashed Action*,  the animation is as desired:

[image]

and I'm also able to edit the followup track where I moved the character to an end point.  However if I *Stop Editing stashed Action* of the jogging sequence, the armature get disoriented:
[image]

So far I've been chasing my tail.

blend file reduced to the core problem: [image].   NOTE: you may have to re-animate the Path after downloading, for some reason.